# JavaScript issue in Internet explorer while using webbrowserdialog box control C#

Tags: javascript, c#, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I have written a program in C#, i use webbrowser dialog box control in my program.

There is some problem with one of the java script.

Internet Explorer gives me warning message. "one of the Script is slowing down".

I am not getting any way, i can debug the java script in IE(because webbrowser dialog box control use it indirectly).

Is there any tool i can install which can give me some information on the javascript which is causing the problem.

*There are lot many javascripts , so tracing won't be possible. ( i have tried tracing few).

Comment: I dunno what version of IE you're using, but have you tried pressing F12 and opening the javascript console?

Comment: :( IE 11. F12 doesn't give anything. may be because it is used indirectly.

Comment: Go to Tools -> Developer tools. I've also got IE11, F12 should work